# Using combine function in QGIS modeler

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-modeler, model, combine

I am trying to use the QGIS modeler with the 'combine' function, but when I run the model, it only gives me one choice of shapefile to choose instead of letting me choose more than one raster to combine.

How do I do that?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the model

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to find which "combine" function you are trying to use, but in general, what you need to do in the modeller is to define all the selectable indata layers as separate inputs, then you define your model steps to work on those, for an example, if I was to make a model to run a union on two layers, it could be like this:

[image]

(Sorry, my QGIS setup is in Norwegian, but the important things are the two input layers then I select one for each of the inputs of the model)

If I have misunderstood your question, please add a bit more explanation on which function you try to use and a screenshot of what the relevant parts of your model looks like.